# How to get video full duration and current playing time?

Tags: ios, swift, video

I need to create a custom video plugin using swift. But I don't know how to get video full duration and current playing time. In my console just appeared this output, `C.CMTime`. I'm not sure what wrong with my code.

My code

```
let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Video", withExtension:"mp4")
let asset = AVURLAsset(URL:url, options:nil)
let duration: CMTime = asset.duration

println(duration)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use CMTimeGetSeconds to converts a CMTime to seconds.

```
let durationTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
```

Comment: i got this error message,  'Float64' is not convertible to 'CMTime'

Comment: Why you convert Float64 to CMTime again?

Answer (score 0):

Use ios Objective c concept

```
- (NSTimeInterval) playableDuration
{
   //  use loadedTimeRanges to compute playableDuration.
   AVPlayerItem * item = _moviePlayer.currentItem;

   if (item.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay) {
   NSArray * timeRangeArray = item.loadedTimeRanges;

   CMTimeRange aTimeRange = [[timeRangeArray objectAtIndex:0]    CMTimeRangeValue];

   double startTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(aTimeRange.start);
   double loadedDuration = CMTimeGetSeconds(aTimeRange.duration);

  // FIXME: shoule we sum up all sections to have a total playable duration,
  // or we just use first section as whole?

   NSLog(@"get time range, its start is %f seconds, its duration is %f seconds.", startTime, loadedDuration);


   return (NSTimeInterval)(startTime + loadedDuration);
  }
  else
  {
     return(CMTimeGetSeconds(kCMTimeInvalid));
  }

}
```

Comment: sorry I have no swift language idea