# Get the accurate duration of a video

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avasset

I'm making a player and I want to list all files and in front of all files I want to present the duration of the video.

The only problem is that I'm not getting the right video duration, sometimes it return a duration completely wrong.

I've tried the below solution:

```
let asset = AVAsset(url: "video.mp4")

let duration = asset.duration.seconds
```

So that it, the time sometimes give a value sometimes another.
if someone know a possible solution I'm glad to heard.

I have update the code using one possible solution but it didn't work well,

```
let asset = AVAsset(url: url)

let duration = asset.duration

let durationTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)

let minutes = Double(durationTime / 60)
```

I've tried with a video of 11:47 minutes of duration and it returns me = 11:78, how could a video have 11 minutes and 78 seconds?

So I think the problem is with the video, and I picked another video of 1:16 minutes and again the returned value is 1:26 (10 seconds wrong)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157526/how-to-get-video-full-duration-and-current-playing-time

Comment: I've already try it, and the time keep crazy values @Eric Aya

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This works for me:

```
import AVFoundation
import CoreMedia

...

    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "small", withExtension: "mp4") {
        let asset = AVAsset(url: url)

        let duration = asset.duration
        let durationTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)

        print(durationTime)
    }
```

For the video [here](http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4) it prints "5.568" which is correct.

*Edit from comments:*

A video that returns `707` seconds when divided by `60 sec/min` is `11.78`.  This is 11.78 minutes, or 11 minutes and `0.78min * 60sec/min = 47sec`, total is `11 min 47 sec`

Comment: Hey man, I copied a pasted your code, don't change one line and de duration is givin 707 for a video of 11 minutes, so I divided 707 by 60 and it return 11.78, something is wrong. your answer is good but dint't solve my problem , i will keep trying. thxs

Comment: If the video is 11 minutes and 47 seconds long then 707 is correct.  707 seconds is 11.78 minutes.

Comment: But the correct time is 11:47, and how to I get this (11:47), I don't know if I'm not understand something or missing something, can you explain @DavidShaw

Comment: You don't seem to understand the time conversion.  707 seconds is 11.78 minutes.  0.78 minutes is NOT 78 seconds.  0.78min * 60sec/min = 47 sec

Comment: David, I'm soo dumb, now I understand

Comment: it is what i am looking for

Answer (score 3):

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "small", withExtension: "mp4") {
        let asset = AVAsset(url: url)

        let duration = asset.duration
        let durationTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
        let minutes = durationTime/60
        let seconds = durationTime%60
        let videoDuration = "\(minutes):\(seconds)"
        print(videoDuration)
    }
```

Comment: When 707 divide by 60 it gives 11 minutes and the remaining is seconds, so by using remainder you can get the remaining seconds of the video like 707%60.