# Get Vimeo video duration in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, vimeo

I am wondering how can i get the video duration in Swift i have already managed to show the video from Vimeo by using the video link and then extract it and. Now is there any way so that i get the time of that video?, Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://vimeo.com/[video_id]")!
HCVimeoVideoExtractor.fetchVideoURLFrom(url: url, completion: { ( video:HCVimeoVideo?, error:Error?) -> Void in                
    if let err = error {                    
        print("Error = \(err.localizedDescription)")                    
        return
    }
    
    guard let vid = video else {
        print("Invalid video object")
        return
    }
    
    print("Title = \(vid.title), url = \(vid.videoURL), thumbnail = \(vid.thumbnailURL)")
        
    if let videoURL = vid.videoURL[.Quality1080p] {
        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
        let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerController.player = player
        self.present(playerController, animated: true) {
            player.play()
        }
    }                            
}
```

Comment: Where is the part where you try to get the duration?

Answer (score 3):

Once you get the video's url with `if let videoURL`, you can create an `AVAsset` from it and get its duration. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267013/get-the-accurate-duration-of-a-video) for more details.

```
let asset = AVAsset(url: videoURL)
let duration = asset.duration
let durationTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
let minutes = Double(durationTime / 60)
```

Comment: If you know something is a duplicate, do not answer: vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @matt ok, sorry :(

Comment: No problem, thanks for pointing out the duplicate!